# TCP forwarding over SSH using non-root account

Tags: ssh, forwarding

I've setup TCP forwarding over SSH using the following command:

```
ssh -N -L 1234:10.0.2.2:1234 root@10.0.2.1
```

This works no problem. So I decided to create a non-root account `user1` on 10.0.2.1 to do this in a more secure/safer way. However, I get a `permission denied` error message when I try to the same command with the `user1` account.

Comment: Are you confident that the error relates to the port forward operation, have you ensured the user can use ssh?

Comment: Is there any "Match User ...." directives in your sshd_config?

Comment: Aha! Thanks Tim - there was an entry in the sshd_config which was screwing things up.

Comment: Can you post the solution below?

Comment: @JimR No problem, glad it worked!

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Answer posted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some distro's come with a premade sshd_config that has separate permissions based on a username or group, example:

```
Match User anoncvs
       X11Forwarding no
       AllowTcpForwarding no
       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Jim most likely resolved this by commenting out, or adjusting the directive to match the permissions he needed.

More info available via `man sshd`

Comment: That's useful to know - I'm not too familiar with the 'Match' syntax, but I guess it speaks for itself.

Comment: I just commented this out as you said.